# Adding a column to a dataframe in pandas with proper indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames each of one column. One data frame is "contained" in the other in the sense that the index values and corresponding data are included in the other. In a way, the sub-data frame is just filtered data from the first.

I want to take the data from the sub-data frame and append it to a new column on the super-data frame where the index values in common have the corresponding shared data and the index values that are not in the sub-data frame simply have an np.nan as data.

So far I have `df2` "contained" in `df1` (i.e. the filtered data).

```
column1 = df1[0]
column2 = df2[0]

indx1 = df1.index
indx2 = df2.index

n = len(df1[column1])
m = len(df2[column2])

a = a = np.zeros(n)
a[:] = np.nan

df1['filtered'] = pd.Series(a, index=indx1)

i = 0
j = 0

while i < n:
    while j < m:
        if indx1.values[i] == indx2.values[j]:
            df1['filtered'].set_value(indx1[i], df2[column2].get_value(indx2[j]))
        t = j
        break

    i = i+1
    j = t+1
```

However this is not working for me, so any advice would be much appreciated. since it is syntactically correct (assuming I wrote it down here correctly), but it just runs forever.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a sample of your dataframes and the expected output?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your dataframes and the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use concat in this way:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

df1:
  Column 1
1     0001
2     0001
3     0002
4     0002
5     0003
6     0003
7     0003

df2:
  Column 2
3     0001
4     0001
5     0002

output:
  Column 1 Column 2
1     0001      NaN
2     0001      NaN
3     0002     0001
4     0002     0001
5     0003     0002
6     0003      NaN
7     0003      NaN
```

Comment: I think this way is more straight forward for a beginner like me. Thanks

Comment: Welcome :) Besides accepting this answer, you can also upvote both answers if you find them useful

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to guess what you want to achieve.

```
df1
Out[927]: 
          A
0  0.077544
1  0.450615
2  0.427897
3  0.729260
4  0.679355
5  0.275869
6  0.441755
7  0.996711
8  0.358979
9  0.552371

df2
Out[928]: 
          A
4  0.679355
5  0.275869
6  0.441755
7  0.996711

pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',left_index=True,right_index=True)
Out[929]: 
        A_x       A_y
0  0.077544       NaN
1  0.450615       NaN
2  0.427897       NaN
3  0.729260       NaN
4  0.679355  0.679355
5  0.275869  0.275869
6  0.441755  0.441755
7  0.996711  0.996711
8  0.358979       NaN
9  0.552371       NaN
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept it as answer if u find it useful.